# encountered during startup: A node with address already exists

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra 3.6 and 3 node of cassandra

seed node is in 111.1.11.111 this ip

and two other node is in 222.2.22.222 this ip

```
storage_port:                   node3=7000, node2=7005
ssl_storage_port:               node3=7001, node2=7006
native_transport_port:          node3=9042, node2=9043  
rpc_port:                       node3=9160, node2=9161
```

when I start cassandra service  using "service cassandra start"

error will throw on cassandra.log file

> Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup: A
>   node with address /222.2.22.222 already exists, cancelling join. Use
>   cassandra.replace_address if you want to replace this node.

*Note: I am using same ip address (222.2.22.222) for node2 and node3 but port are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple nodes can not have the same IP address.  All nodes need to use different IP's and keep the ports the same.